# Permission Level regarding users

Tags: trigger

Normally trigger works in user mode in salesforce,I have write a trigger on order product object,for one particular user, the field has readable permission.Is it possible to update the value in the field using trigger? If Possible How? can anyone please suggest answer

Comment: Triggers work in system mode so you can update the field just fine

Comment: It will be updated.